# App fails to replace label text with UUID

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am trying to work on a program that will change a label to a user's UUID but for some reason it does not work and I can't seem to figure out since I'm still learning the language. Below is my attempt. This is the ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

    @IBAction func getuuid(sender: AnyObject) {
        text.text = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you ever call getuuid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a breakpoint on the line where you set the text.text value to the UUID. Odds are, you are missing the connection from your storyboard to the function call. To test this, click on the button once the breakpoint is in place, and if you see it freeze the code at that spot, then your connection is at least working. If it does not freeze there, then you need to connect the getuuid function to your button.